# How do i generate JWT token from android

Tags: android, token, jwt

How do i generate JWT token from android. I tried the following :

```
 token = JWT.create().withClaim("email",username)
                        .sign(Algorithm.HMAC256("secret"));
                System.out.println(" JWS token : "+ token);
```

But i got this exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeBase64URLSafeString([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
                                                          at com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator.sign(JWTCreator.java:283)
                                                          at com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator.access$100(JWTCreator.java:23)
                                                          at com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator$Builder.sign(JWTCreator.java:264)
                                                          at se.stigasoft.netwrapper.NetCom.jwtWork(NetCom.java:321)
```

I tried other methos from some other library too.

```
 String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject("Joe")
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret".getBytes())
            .compact();
```

this one generates the token. But i dont know how to send my  data like name,value pair that i used to send in the post method .

. Please help

Comment: When asking a question like that, please specify which library are you using, since this is not part of core Android platform.

Answer (score 8):

To generate JWT token there is the way to generate:

1) add dependency in gradle

```
implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
```

2) add the following code on the basis of the parameters.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             String jwt = Jwts.builder().claim("emailId","test123@gmail.com").claim("emailIdOTP", "123456")
                .claim("phoneNo", "1111111111")
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret".getBytes())
                .compact();
                Log.v("JWT : - ",jwt);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After much digging in the internet for last day I found the solution to this

```
  String compactJws = Jwts.builder().claim("email",username).claim("password",password)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret".getBytes())
                .compact()
```

this is the correct way to generate the token from the app side. So that the data is not sent in plain header.

Comment: What is the name/ dependency need to add for the implementation of the above mentioned code?

Comment: This is misleading, as the data is still sent as plaintext - it is just base64 encoded.  Do NOT send passwords using this manner, as they can be read by anyone, and is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin Generate using this

```
val jws1 = Jwts.builder()
            .setIssuer("issuer")
            .setSubject("subject")
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "key".toByteArray()).compact()
        Log.d("SHUBH", "onCreate: $jws1")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).